# Python manage.py error, it´s for Intel M1?

Tags: python, django, macos, django-models, apple-m1

I wanted to know if you could help me, the question is that when I do a makemigrations in Django or Python I get this error and I have not been able to fix it, and I have not been able to start the server to work, I do not know if something similar has happened and I can tell me what to do, it is on a MacBook M1

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jesusochoagonzalez/Documents/GitHub/cip_django/aplications/globaldata/views.py", line 1, in <module>
    from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/windows_events.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise ImportError('win32 only')
ImportError: win32 only
```

Comment: Your view imports `asyncio.windows_events`, which is only available on Windows operating system, not macOS.

Comment: then I will not be able to work on the system in macOS?

Comment: It appears so...

Comment: Yes, you can work in macOS, just remove that import.

Answer (score 0):

go to `/Users/jesusochoagonzalez/Documents/GitHub/cip_django/aplications/globaldata/views.py`

and look leave this line `from asyncio.windows_events import NULL`

it's just causes by auto import of your IDE ,it's import NULL from `asyncio.windows_events` in place to use NULL that is defined in python.